# How to retrieve editorial_summary from a place of Google API Places?

Tags: google-places-api

I recently started to create an React application that retrieve informations from the Google Places API but I noticed that certain informations can't be retrieve, especially atmosphere data field **editorial_summary** who gives a little explanation of the place. I tried to make a lot of requests with this parameter on a place that I know that editorial_summary exists (for example : Les ventres jaunes restaurant in Lyon)(see [screnshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3T2f.png) with results in console without the field and the summary existing when you search the place on [screnshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAZJJ.png) and this one, as you can see, is not based on Wikipedia page..).

Ok sooo I read again the documentation and I find some distinctions between [services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clcQo.png) ? Someone can explain to me whats the difference between this two columns and how I can retrieve editorial_summary ? I will be eternally grateful to you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For us to know what's wrong and to help you better, it is recommended that we provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: @Jynrohan did you able to get the data?

Comment: definitely no... :(